# Execute only one Talend Component

Tags: talend

In Talend Open Studio, how do I execute only one of my components? If I click Run, all active components will run. So far the only way I know to execute a single component is to deactivate all others in the Job.

How can I execute one component or subjob without having to deactivate all the other components in the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm afraid you can't.

Two possible solutions :

- Deactivating unwanted components / subjobs (like you already stated)
- Decompose your job into multiple jobs. This may give you more flexibility. You can then use the `tBufferOutput` component to pass information from the child job to his parent.

Comment: I ended up using a combination of both methods.