# Run a specific talend component using the shell executable

Tags: talend

My question is similar to this: [Execute only one talend component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802231/execute-only-one-talend-component?rq=1). Except instead of using the Talend Open Studio, I want to be able to run a specific component from the shell executable I get from building the job.

I have set up my job in a way that if a component is succeeded, the `OnComponentOk` trigger is used to run the next component. To run the job I run `sudo bash NAME_OF_THE_JOB.sh`. Is it possible to run only one component, perhaps by passing arguments to the bash shell file?

Answer (score 0):

A Talend job is a single java program. Components are translated to java functions. There are no arguments that allow you to execute a single component.
What you could do is write your job in such a way to execute a component whose name is passed via a context variable but it's not pretty.
You can test the component name passed via a variable named componentName using `Run If` triggers:

```
     tRunJob_1
        /
   if("tRunJob_1".equals(context.componentName)
      /
     /
Start ---if("tJava_2".equals(context.componentName))-- tJava_2
     \
      \
   if("tRest_1".equals(context.componentName))
        \
       tRest_1
```

As you can see, this can get very cumbersome, and requires you to know the component's name in order to run it.

You can then launch your job by passing the component name as argument :

```
sudo bash NAME_OF_THE_JOB.sh --context_param componentName=tJava_2
```